# how scopus recognizes which papers are mine

Tags: publications

I didn't create a scopus ID, but scopus is able to recognize and collect all my publications even though I have multiple affiliations. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably it uses your name, affiliations, and field(s). It might also use the dates of publication, names of collaborators, etc.

It doesn't sound very surprising to me that it can do this with reasonably high accuracy. If your name is unusual, then that on its own would be enough.

Also, Scopus is not perfect and does makes mistakes.

Comment: But how can they recognize and tell that different publications 
by different affiliations have connections and thus were published by the same person

Comment: As I said, it probably uses other information and not just your name. And it does not always get it right.

Comment: Purpose of my question is exactly where this other Information comes from

Comment: It comes from the publications.